Extract the fields from the Json String in the splunk
In the splunk enterprise, i can see the event message as
{ [-]
   Level: Info
   MessageTemplate: {@Logger}
   Properties: { [-]
     Logger: { [-]
       AssetId: 13
       Location: india
       Name: test
     }
   }
   RenderedMessage: {"AssetId":13, "Name":"test", "Location":"india"} 
}

when i use the code(dotnet) as
    var logData = new 
    {
        AssetId = 13,
        Name = "test",
        Location = "india"
    };

   
    _logger.LogInformation("{@logger}",logData);

but i want to extract the individual fields from the message to search that by filter
if the splunk message becames like the below  , it would be enough for me
{ [-]
   Level: Info
   MessageTemplate: { [-]       
       AssetId: 13
       Location: india
       Name: test
   }
   Properties: { [-]       
       AssetId: 13
       Location: india
       Name: test
   }
   RenderedMessage: { [-]       
       AssetId: 13
       Location: india
       Name: test
   }
}

